# Global Mapper: Slovenian LiDAR very little shift on projection

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, global-mapper, slovenia

I downloaded LiDAR data from Slovenia (link on the bottom). After searching google for the right projection, I found that normally I should use MGI 1901/Slovene National Grid; EPSG:3912 or Slovenia 1996/Slovenian national grid EPSG:3794.

With these EPSG codes, the projection is somewhere in the water.
So I went on searching and found the EPSG code 3787. That's something Military Geographic.

These projection is almost correct, but I still have to shift the False Northing about 8 Meters. Yet I have very little difference on the Lidar projection.

In Global Mapper my main projection is set to Mercator and I am using the normal World Imagery as my base map.

The LiDAR files are from this site:
[Lida GIS Viewer](http://gis.arso.gov.si/evode/profile.aspx?id=atlas_voda_Lidar@Arso&culture=en-US) (on the right side, check one of the checkboxes and click in one or more square on the map to download)

What do I have to do, to get the projection correct?

Comment: Your link points just to data viewer. Where did you download your data from? In what format?

Comment: On the right side you can choose Lidar - just check the red one and you will get a raster. When you click on a raster, you will get a button to download the file/s.
I downloaded the .laz format.

Comment: If you downloaded data with D48GK projection, that's definitely old Slovenian EPSG:3912 (see remarks at http://epsg.io/3912). If you downloaded data with D96TM projection, that's definitely new Slovenian EPSG:3794 (see the same remarks).

Comment: hmm, its absolutly not wiórking for me.
As soon as I load the Lidar file and add either the old or the new EPSG, its on a complete wrong position.
When I use these military EPSG, its almost correct.
Did you try loading it into Global Mapper?

Comment: Update: Its working with the new Slovenian EPSG now...
I made a little mistake by loading first the base map and after that the Lidar.
Loading the Lidar first, using EPSG:3794 and after that loading the basemap, did the trick.
Thx alot @TomazicM

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, you can publish solution as an answer to your own question. This way it will be clear problem was solved and your description of how you solved it may help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

To get a 100% accurate overlap with the base map, I imported the Lidar files first (not the base map) and chose EPSG:3794.

After loading the Lidar, I added the the base map as a second layer.

That way the two projections are overlapping 100% accurate.